# Finding the correct child view of ListView while clicking a button within it

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener, baseadapter

I am conducting an experiment to try and understand the `ListView` lifecycle.

I have a `ListView`, in each row I have a button and a `TextView`, my experiment will be to click a `Button` and have the row be painted green, here is the code:

EDIT:

I tried using an array of booleans but got the same result

```
    package com.ziv.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.ziv.test.Fr.mAdapter.ViewHolder;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fr extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<String> list;
    private ListView lv;

    public Fr() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        list = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            list.add("item number " + i);
        }

        lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            mAdapter adapter = new mAdapter(list, lv);
            lv.setAdapter(a

dapter);

        return view;
    }

    public class mAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<String> list;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ListView lv;

    // boolean[] for button state:
    private Boolean[] clickedButtonPositions;

    public mAdapter(ArrayList<String> list, ListView lv) {

        this.list = list;
        this.lv = lv;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
         this.clickedButtonPositions = new Boolean[list.size()];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // here you write everything is related to views...
        // do not forget to reuse...

        ViewHolder vh;
        if (convertView == null) {

            vh = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_cell, null);

            vh.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_test);
            vh.btn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_button);

            convertView.setTag(vh);

        } else {


            vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        }
        vh.text.setText(list.get(position));

        vh.btn.setTag(R.id.list_button, position);

        vh.btn.setOnClickListener(OnClickButton);



        return convertView;

    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
        Button btn;

    }



    private View.OnClickListener OnClickButton = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // v will always be the view that received the click event, no
            // need to check.
            int pos = (int) v.getTag(R.id.list_button);
            LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) lv.getChildAt(pos);

            // Switching the 'clicked' value for this button - If you want
            // the button to "turn off" the view
            clickedButtonPositions[pos] = !clickedButtonPositions[pos];
            // If you don't want the button to "turn off" the view use this
            // line instead:
            // clickedButtonPositions[pos] = true;

            // save button state in a local variable, optional
            boolean clicked = clickedButtonPositions[pos];

            // If you want a "turn off" behavior use this line with the '?:'
            // operator
            view.setBackgroundColor(clicked ? Color.GREEN : Color.LTGRAY);
            // If you don't want a "turn off" behavior this will do:

        }
    };
}
```

}

[image]

However, much to my disappointment, the row I click was not the only one painted green, its recycled row was painted as well, the one that was just outside the screen.
how can i isolate my desired row in a click event?

Comment: something is wrong with my question? why downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced a similar problem in my project and was extending base adapter like you did. My solution was really simple. It goes like this:

```
if(buttonClick)//any boolean variable indicating clicked
{
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
}else{
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Comment: are you changing the background to green and the back to white?, the experiment is low scale but eventually i will want to make big changes to the view not just changing background color

Comment: It so happened that when I changed background color of one item another at some other position was also changed. To avoid it I reset it to the default background color inside getView. I can post java file that I used to overcome it but i doubt it will be fruitful. the code i mentioned is a base concept of my solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a boolean array for all your `ListView` items.

In `onClick()`, only set to true/false for the right position. Then call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your adapter.

In `getView()`, set the color depending on your boolean array.

Comment: this seems like it might work but could get messed up when the UI gets more complicated, this experiment is simple but what i actually want to do is far more complicated, i feel like this is a common problem and there has to be a standard solution for it.

Comment: Sorry but this is not an experiment. Good luck finding a complicated solution for this simple problem ;-).

Comment: why the sarcazem? i am trying to find out if there is a proper way of handaling this situation, putting my exact problem with my exact code will not help other people that are running in to this problem.